# How to display a gallery of small picture icons in a Left-Right-Horizontal navigatable style, like in JavaScript/ JQuery

Tags: java, javafx

This is usually done in *JavaScript/ JQuery*. I'd like an implementation in *Java/ JavaFx.*

***A bit more details:***

I have a gallery of pictures I'd like to list, first as small ***32*** * ***32***, then when a user clicks on one of the ***32*** * ***32*** icons, a larger one of the clicked should appear on another pane.

The problem I have is listing them horizontally so that a user could use ***Left-Right*** navigation arrows on either edge to show other new pictures not yet in view ***(more 32 by 32 picture icons become visible as others slide out of view either to the Left or Right)***, so I don't think that TableView's the best way to go.

**I'd like something like this:**

[image]

Please help me on how I could implement this? Thank you in advance....

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [DisplayShelf](https://bitbucket.org/openjfxmirrors/openjfx-8-master-rt/src/tip/apps/samples/Ensemble8/src/samples/java/ensemble/samples/graphics2d/displayshelf/?at=default) example from the Java 8 Ensemble 8 sample application.

The sample is more complex than what you need, but you could probably learn from it, simplify it and adapt it for your work.

The Ensemble 8 application is in the [Java 8 Demos and Samples](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) download for Java 8, so you can easily download and run it (use `java -jar Ensemble8.jar`) out of the `demo/javafx_samples` directory.  Then search for DisplayShelf from within the Ensemble 8 application.

[image: zookeeper]