# Stackpane - MouseClick to be listened by both its children

Tags: javafx

**Background**

I am trying to build a image gallery based on the description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22708506/how-to-display-a-gallery-of-small-picture-icons-in-a-left-right-horizontal-navig).

I have a `StackPane`, with `ScrollPane` and `AnchorPane` as its children, added in the same order.

*ScrollPane* contains a list of images contained in ImageView's, while the *Anchorpane* has two buttons, anchored to the left and right corners, to scroll the images !

[image: An image which describes the layout]

**Problem**

The scrolling is working fine, as the buttons are placed on the AnchorPane, which is the top child on the StackPane.

**I want to implement the double-click on the imageView to open it in fullscreen**. Since the *imageView* is a child of *ScrollPane*, it is not able to listen to the mouse event.

Is there a way through which I can make the ImageView listen to the mouseEvent ?

Comment: Your layout requirements aren't really clear to me. Is the idea that the buttons appear to float above the `ScrollPane`? Is the problem that the `AnchorPane` is receiving the mouse events and preventing them propagating to the buttons?

Comment: Exactly, the buttons should float on the ScrollPane. The buttons, being a part of the AnchorPane are able to receive MouseEvents. But, the scrollpane, which lie underneath the AnchorPane is not able to receive it. I want the mouse events to be received by the ScrollPane(or to be more specific, its children, the  ImageViews)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of placing the `AnchorPane` and `ScrollPane` in a `StackPane`, try using the `AnchorPane` as the root of this structure. Add the `ScrollPane` to it first with appropriate anchors and then add the buttons. That way the buttons will still be on top, but there will be nothing interfering with the mouse events on the content of the scroll pane.

```
ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
scrollPane.setContent(...);


// scrollPane fills entire anchor pane:

AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(scrollPane, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(scrollPane, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(scrollPane, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(scrollPane, 0.0);

Button button1 = new Button(...);
Button button2 = new Button(...);

// button1 in top left:
AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(button1, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(button1, 0.0);

// button2 in top right:
AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(button2, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(button2, 0.0);

AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
anchorPane.getChildren().addAll(scrollPane, button1, button2);
```

Comment: This works perfectly for this part, but I would like to know, if there a way to make the `first child of StackPane` listen to **Events** ?

Comment: If you use your original design, try calling `setMouseTransparant(true)` on the `AnchorPane`

Comment: Well, I have already tried it. In this case, the `buttons` on the `AnchorPane` will also stop responding to `MouseEvents`